# How to scroll a div using selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to write a script that prints out all the active friends from facebook web. I'm having difficulty scrolling the div that contains the active friends list

I was trying to scroll the active chat list on facebook and its not working

```
    username = driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(input_email)
    password = 
    driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys(input_password)
    login = driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(40)
    scroll_active_friends_list = driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_1y")
    driver.execute_script("scroll_active_friends_list.animate({scrollTop: 
    '100px'})")
```

JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: scroll_active_friends_list is not defined
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the WebDriverWait instead of implicit wait for the elements to be loaded and `location_once_scrolled_into_view` method that will scroll to the element.

**Imports needed:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Script**

```
username = driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(input_email)
password = driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys(input_password)
login = driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton").click()
# wait for the div to be present
scroll_active_friends_list = WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID("u_0_1y"))))
scroll_active_friends_list.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didnt work out
This is the error message it displayed.



`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-43317506dbe4> in <module>
----> 1 scroll_active_friends_list = WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.id("u_0_1y"))))
      2 scroll_active_friends_list.location_once_scrolled_into_view

AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: Try with the updated answer. It should be `By.ID`, somehow I mentioned it as 'By.id`.